# Google Maps example does not work in IE7 & IE8

Tags: google-maps

When I try to load the following page in IE7 & IE8 I receive an error:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple

The error states: "attribute only valid in v:image inside google's main.js" (see attached)

[image: error image displayed]

This is a simple example of what is actually happening in my own application as well.  Any idea of how I could resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posted example works fine for me in ie8.  ie has serious caching issues at times,  have you tried clearing your temporary files and re-running the example?

Comment: We have tried that and it did not fix anything. This error is only happening on one out of 5 machines, we're not sure why.

Comment: Could be a security setting on that machine. Try comparing the internet options on that machine with one of the others.  You also may want to try re-installing ie.

Comment: Great suggestions @javram, I agree with this. We currently dont have permissions to view IE settings but will definitely let u know when we figure it out.

Comment: Have you found a way to resolve this? Some documentation of google leads this error to a bug contained in the PicLens application... Do you know anithing else about it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I couldn't solve it but bypass by disabling the "pancontrol" in the map. I disabled the default controls in the map and enabled the zoom control manually. When doing this for the pancontrol I was running into "attribute only valid on v:image" again.

```
    myMapOptions = {
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      zoomControl: true,
      zoomControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
      },                        
      center: mymapcenter,
      zoom: 7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
    };

    mymap    = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                myMapOptions);
```